# Non absolute or fixed div over map

Tags: html, css, mapbox

I'm using a modified version of cssgrid.net to match my needs making a website. Now I'm trying to have a MapBox map as a background for a `div` that is over it, but my problem is with dragging, because the wrapper of the div over the map doesn't allow me to drag the map.

As I can see with the DOM Inspector, the wrapper `div.row` uses the whole horizontal space available, not allowing to drag the map below it.

I've reproduced my problem [in a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MAJSY/), so you can see the actual markup and CSS I'm using.

**EDIT:** I took a screencap of the problem I'm having. Here `div.row` takes the horizontal space because is defined as `max-width: 1140px; margin: 0 auto;`. That means if I change its width, it gets centered, and if I change its margins, it pulls itself to the left.

[image: Screen capture of layout]

Also, a thing I found out while testing is that setting a `padding` doesn't allow me to click through, but setting a `margin` does.

Answer (score 1):

I removed `.trecio`, and changed `.row div`.

Change the width of `.row` the way you see it best, I've set it `width:180px;`

```
.row  {
    clear:both;
    margin-left:10px;
    overflow:hidden;

    width:180px;
}
```

Check it out : http://jsfiddle.net/WxALp/

Again I removed `.tercio`, give `.row` a `float:left;` and `.container` an `overflow:hidden;`

```
.container {
    padding: 3em 20px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.row  {
    clear: both;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    float:left;

}
```

Check it: http://jsfiddle.net/AliBassam/ZHZtU/

Comment: I tried what you tell me, but it doesn't do what I need, because it pulls the div.row to the left, which breaks the purpose of using cssgrid.net base (a 1140px central container for columns).

Comment: @noquierouser I updated my answer. I'm trying to give the row.div a good position and a fixed with, so that you can use the map on the right of this div. It's working in the fiddle.